# Jersey: how to set MediaType to javax.ws.rs.core.Response, if real "physical" response header does not have any information about it

Tags: java, rest, http-headers, jersey, jax-rs

When I send request to server

```
...
Response response = builder.method(req.getMethod(), Entity.entity(req, req.getMediaType())); // req.getMediaType() return MediaType.APPLICATION_XML
if(response.getStatus() != 200)
   throw new CoreErrorException("core resulted error with status = " + response.getStatus());
T resp = response.readEntity(respType);
...
```

Jersey throw exception on the last line:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=application/octet-stream
```

I did some investigation. First of all, I catch that response:

```
Content-Length: 93
Date: Thu, 21 Nov 2013 12:53:46 GMT
Server: APP

<root>
   <returncode>XXX</returncode>
   <desc>some description</desc>
</root>
```

Header does not contain any information about MediaType.

Indeed, when I try to call **response.getMediaType()**, it returns **null**.

I think, that is the problem. Jersey cann't detect MediaType of response and set it by default ("application/octet-stream"). But in really the body of my response is XML. Is there some way to tell Jersey about it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to add `Accept` header into your request by calling `WebTarget#request(MediaType)`,

```
ClientBuilder.newClient()
    .target("mytarget")
    .request("application/xml")
    .method(req.getMethod(), Entity.entity(req, req.getMediaType()));
```

whether the server doesn't add `Content-Type` header to the response. If not you can try to change the headers on the client site using `WriterInterceptor` or simply by calling

```
Response response = ...;
response.getStringHeaders().putSingle(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain");
T resp = response.readEntity(respType);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The second solution was helpful for me.